# How can I call the id number of a supplier, that is in a link, call it from a controller

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two tables, proveedors (suppliers) and productos (products).

Also I have a controller, in_stock_proveedors. In this view I show the list of all proveedors, all this proveedors has a link, where I call its id.

I would like know how can I call this id proveedors, from the link that I have in index (in_stock_proveedors), to proveedors controler.

This is my `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :productos
resources :proveedors
resources :in_stock_proveedors
devise_for :usuarios
get "/stock_proveedors", to: "proveedors#get_stock"
```

This is the link, that I have in_stock_proveedors, where from where I call
 the id of the proveedor that I choose:

```
link_to "Ir al proveedor", stock_proveedors_path(:value =>{:id=>item['proveedors.id']})
```

This the method, in proveedors controller, where I want to receive the id number from the link, with the param p

```
def get_stock
  @p = Proveedor.find(params[:id])

  sql = 'SELECT productos.id as producto, productos.nombre as nombre  
      FROM productos
      INNER JOIN proveedors ON productos.proveedor_id = proveedors.id
      WHERE productos.proveedor_id = @p
      GROUP BY productos.id'
  @aux= ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)  
end
```

This is the index, of in_stock_proveedors

> 

item['proveedors.id'])%>

This is the in_stock_proveedors controller

```
def index
sql3= "SELECT
proveedors.nombre as proveedor,
COUNT(productos.id) as distintos,
COUNT(CASE WHEN productos.stock > '0' THEN productos.id END) as instock,
proveedors.id 
FROM proveedors
INNER JOIN productos ON proveedors.id = productos.proveedor_id
GROUP BY proveedors.id" 
@aux3= ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql3)    
end
```

This is the schema,for proveedors

```
create_table "proveedors", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "nombre"
t.string   "direccion"
t.string   "email"
t.string   "telefono"
t.string   "rut"
t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
t.string   "pais"
t.string   "pagina_web"
t.integer  "producto_id"
t.integer  "orden_de_compra_id"
t.index ["orden_de_compra_id"], name: "index_proveedors_on_orden_de_compra_id"
t.index ["producto_id"], name: "index_proveedors_on_producto_id"
end
```

Comment: Pass just the param you're expecting `link_to "Ir al proveedor", stock_proveedors_path(value: item['proveedors.id'])`.

Comment: Why do you have `{ }` in routes

Comment: what's your schema for `proveedors`?

Comment: @Pavan was a typing error

Comment: I wrote the schema for provedors  @Md.FarhanMemon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your controller action for the index page is something like

```
def index
  sql = 'SELECT * FROM proveedors'
  @proovedors = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

loop through the `@proovedors` list in your index view file;

```
<% @proovedors.each do |proveedor| %>
  <%= link_to "Ir al proveedor", stock_proveedors_path(:id => proveedor['id']) %>
<% end %>
```

Then, access `params[:id]` in your controller action

```
def get_stock
  @p = Proveedor.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

Comment: Hi, I got this error, Couldn't find Proveedor with 'id'=